# Can I mix C++ and C in a single project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, winapi

I have a a Win32 DLL project in VS2008, it is written in a handful of C modules.
Because I *also* want to be able to build outside VS2008, with no dependency on VS2008, I have produced a custom makefile, that does all the build and link steps. All this is set up just fine.

Now I'd like to add a couple C++ modules to this DLL. 
I have modified the custom makefile to compile the .cpp modules as C++, and the .c modules as regular C (/Tc) .  This all works.  It links everything together, no problem .

Can I configure the VS2008 project to do the same?

Can I mix C++ and C in the same VS2008 project?

Or do I need a custom build step for this?

Thanks.

---

**ANSWER**

I had the VS2008 project set to compile as C.  I needed to change it to Compile As "Default".   Right click the project, select Properties, and then... :

[image]

Thanks, Pavel.

Comment: I just select file .c from Solution explorer "Properties" -> then compile as C code. And its work :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't even need `/Tc` if you're building it yourself - cl.exe uses file extension to determine the type, so .c files will be compiled as C by default, and .cpp and .cxx files as C++.

For VS projects, it works in exact same way, except that you can't override this behavior (or at least I do not know how).

Comment: Very helpful.  Turns out there is an option in VS to set the "Compile As" option, one of /Tc , /Tp , or "default".  I had it set to /Tc . I needed to reset it to "default". A-OK.

Answer (score 8):

There's absolutely no problems mixing C and C++ in the same project. All you'll need to do it to design your interface between C and C++ modules in tems of C functions and C data structures, an then make sure that those interface functions are declared on C++ side with C-linkage specifier `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 1):

They should add fine, considering the Microsoft C compiler will compile both.  If you add them to the project, they'll get passed to `cl` -- and I believe `cl` makes a choice what mode to use based on the extension of the file. You're using `.cpp`, which is good.

In short: Yes.

GCC will do this too, so your makefile should be reasonably portable.

Comment: Note that if you're compiling C++ with `gcc`, `gcc` may not add necessary libraries at the link phase. The link step for a C++ program must always use `g++`, not `gcc`